# Issue with DATEADD function in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, tabular, ssas-tabular

I recently started learning DAX. I am unable to understand `DATEADD` function properly. The below expression is giving error.

```
DATEADD(FIRSTNONBLANK(DATATABLE("TodaysDate",DATETIME,{{"9/24/2016"}}),TRUE()),4,MONTH)
```

> A table expression containing more than one column was specified in the call to function 'DATEADD'. This is not supported.

But it's working with `EDATE`

```
EDATE(FIRSTNONBLANK(DATATABLE("TodaysDate",DATETIME,{{"9/24/2016"}}),TRUE()),4)
```

and `FIRSTDATE` is not working like `FIRSTNONBLANK`. Is there a problem with `DATATABLE` usage?

```
FIRSTDATE(DATATABLE("Today1",DATETIME,{{"9/24/2016"}}))
```

> A table expression containing more than one column was specified in the call to function 'FIRSTDATE'. This is not supported.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `DATEADD` function takes a **column** that contains dates as first parameter, you are passing a **table** so that is causing the error. Even if you are passing a one-column table it is different to a column.

Note `FIRSTNONBLANK` and `FIRSTDATE` functions return a **table** containing a single column and single row with the computed first value or date respectively, so you are passing a table.

Even if you were passing one column with one row to the `DATEADD` function it won't throw errors but return nothing since `DATEADD` returns the computed date if it is present in the column, so if you have one value there is no more dates to return. If it is not clear for you, consider this example to understand how `DATEADD` works:

You have this table called `MyDates`

[image]

If you use `DATEADD` to create a calculated column called `4MonthsAfter`:

```
4MonthsAfter = DATEADD(MyDates[Date],4,MONTH)
```

It returns this:

[image]

As you can see the column `4MonthsAfter` for the date `24/08/2016` value is blank since the column doesn't contain `24/12/2016` value, the same happens for `24/01/2017` because there is no `24/05/2017` value. But 4 months after `24/09/2016` is computed since `24/01/2017` is present in the column.

The way `DATEADD` works is pretty different from `EDATE` way. `EDATE` takes a **date** (not a table column of dates) in datetime or text format and compute the given number of months before or after the date.

In essence, `DATEADD` expects a table column of dates as first parameter as most of [Time Intelligence functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634763.aspx), which are designed to work with [Date/Calendar](http://www.agilebi.com.au/power-bi-date-dimension/) tables (Date dimensions).

If you come from a programming background, you could get confused by the way `DATEADD` works in DAX. Commonly `DATEADD` only needs a date, the number of intervals and a specific interval (MONTH, DAY, YEAR, QUARTER) to compute a date, in DAX it requires an explicit column of dates as first parameter.

Let me know if this helps.

**REFERENCES:**

[DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634905.aspx)
[FIRSTNONBLANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634210.aspx)
[FIRSTDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634806.aspx)
[EDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634544.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks, so much clarity on DATEADD now, I have data warehousing knowledge and can relate to DateDimension. I think this is the reason DATEADD is put under time intelligence functions but not under date time functions :)

Comment: Is it the reason that 3rd expression is not working because we are passing a table instead of column? But if that is the case, FIRSTNONBLANK also shouldn't work, should it?

Comment: @Gokul, `FIRSTNONBLANK` first parameter can be a referece to a column, a **table** (what you are passing), or a boolean expression that defines a single-column table. So FIRSTNONBLANK should work, however it returns a table which results in error when DATEADD function is evaluated as explained before.